# CSS specificity of comma-separated group selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

What is the proper way of computing the specificity for comma-separated group selectors?

The specificity for the following selector, for example, is `0,1,2,2` (1 for `head`, 1 for `a`, 10 for `.left`, 10 for `:hover`, and 100 for `#title`):

```
head #title .left a:hover
```

What would be the specificity for this selector? Would it also be `0,1,2,2`? Or is this treated as multiple selectors, and a specificity has to be computed for each?

```
head,#title,.left,a:hover
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you have ONE selector. It is a selector comprised of multiple [simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#selector-syntax) separated by [descendant combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#selector-syntax). But it is still one selector.

In your second example you have FOUR selectors. The comma separates selectors.

> [§5. Groups of
> selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#grouping)
>
> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all
> elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list.
>
> For example, in CSS when several selectors share the same declarations,
> they may be grouped into a comma-separated list.

**Specificity applies to a single selector**, so in your second example, which represents four distinct selectors, you need to calculate the specificity for each one separately.

Think about it this way:

**The purpose of specificity** is to establish which CSS rule gets applied to an HTML element *when there are multiple selectors targeting the same element*.

```css
.intro {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">text</div>
```

Both selectors above are targeting the same element. A class selector has more specificity than a type selector (10 v 1), so the class wins.

On the other hand, a comma-separated list of selectors applies the same rule *to different elements*, so specificity is not an issue.

You don't normally do this:

```css
div, .intro {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">text</div>
```

... because it's redundant.

Comma separation is meant to consolidate selectors like this:

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>text</h1>
<h2>text</h2>
<h3>text</h3>
```

... which has nothing to do with specificity.